# after dismissviewmodalviewcontroller pickerviewmodel value null in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipickerviewcontroller

I am facing an issue which soon will make me crazy. I have `pickermodel`, with numbers. I choose a number from the picker, and then I take picture. When I `dismissmodalviewcontroller`, I can see my `viewcontroller` in the `pickermodel` shows the same number picked but when I try to access by code, it is empty. I am working with `Xamarin.iOs` but this issue I think is related to iOS.

//ViewWillAppear from viewcontroller

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        sitepickerModel = new SitePicker();
        sitepickerModel.Sites.Add(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(this.Title);
        //gets sitesID with the name of Title.
        sitesID = localDb.GetSitesID(this.Title);
        //Adds sites ID(number) to pickermodel
        if (sitesID != null)
        {
            foreach (var s in sitesID)
            {
                sitepickerModel.Sites.Add(s);

            }
        }
        //assigns pickerview to the class pickerModel
        pickerSitesID.Model = sitepickerModel;
        sitepickerModel.ValueChanged += SitepickerModel_ValueChanged;
        siteLabelTxt.Text = sitepickerModel.SelectedSite;
        syncronizeSegment.SelectedSegment = 1;

        if (sitepickerModel.SelectedSite != null)
            Console.WriteLine("View:" + sitepickerModel.SelectedSite);

    }

//CLass UIPickerViewModel
public class SitePicker : UIPickerViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

    //items to show up in the picker
    public List<string> Sites { get; private set; }
    public string SelectedSite
    {
        get
        {

            if (selectedIndex > Sites.Count && selectedIndex > 0)
            {

                selectedIndex = Sites.Count;
                return Sites[selectedIndex];
            }
            else if (selectedIndex == 0 )
            {

                return " ";
            }
            else if (selectedIndex== Sites.Count) {
                selectedIndex = Sites.Count - 1;
                return Sites[selectedIndex];
            }
            else {

                if (Sites[selectedIndex] == " ")
                    return " ";
                else
                    return Sites[selectedIndex];
            }
        }
    }
    int selectedIndex = 0;
    public SitePicker()
    {
        Sites = new List<string>();
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {

        return Sites.Count;
    }
    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        if (NoItem())
            return " ";
        var item = Sites[(int)row];
            return item;

    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        selectedIndex = (int)row;

        if (ValueChanged != null)
        {
            ValueChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
    bool NoItem(int row = 0) 
    {
        return Sites == null || row >= Sites.Count;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code in question

Comment: Once the dismissmodalviewcontroller get called after that viewwillappear method will call again. So debug if you are assigning your pickermodel from there, what values you are getting there?

Comment: Niharika I get null after dismissviewcontroller

Comment: ViewWillAppear method is called after you dismissmodalviewcontroller ? you are assigning sitepickerModel in ViewWillAppear. because of this you are getting null value.

Comment: Niharika, where should assign sitepickerModel in viewdidload?

Comment: @Niharika and the in viewwillAppear what I should do?

Comment: It is working now, just called viewwilappear() Thank you so much

Comment: That's Great :)

Comment: @Niharika not working. When I call another viewcontroller with navigationcontroller to update picker viewmodel, it is not updated because I assign values to picker in viewdidload

Comment: @Niharika I have to update picker from another view, how to do it?